# Improving simultaneous HttpWebRequest performance in c#

Tags: c#

I have an application that batches web requests to a single endpoint using the HttpWebRequest mechanism, the goal of the application is to revise large collections of product listings (specifically their descriptions).

Here is an example of the code I use to make these requests:

```
static class SomeClass
{
    static RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy;

    public static string DoRequest(string requestXml)
    {
        string responseXml = string.Empty;
        Uri ep = new Uri(API_ENDPOINT);
        HttpWebRequest theRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ep);

        theRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        theRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        theRequest.Method = "POST";
        theRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";
        theRequest.Proxy = null;

        if (cachePolicy == null) {
            cachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
        }

        theRequest.CachePolicy = cachePolicy;

        using (Stream requestStream = theRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
            {
                requestWriter.Write(requestXml);
            }
        }

        WebResponse theResponse = theRequest.GetResponse();

        using (Stream responseStream = theResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                responseStream.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] resultBytes = GzCompressor.Decompress(ms.ToArray());
                responseXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);
            }
        }

        return responseXml;
    }
}
```

My question is this; If I thread the task, I can call and complete at most 3 requests per second (based on the average sent data length) and this is through a gigabit connection to a router running business grade fibre internet. However if I divide the task up into 2 sets, and run the second set in a second process, I can double the requests complete per second.

The same can be said if I divide the task into 3 or 4 (after that performance seems to plateau unless I grab another machine to do the same), why is this? and can I change something in the first process so that running multiple processes (or computers) is no longer needed?

Things I have tried so far include the following:

- Implementing GZip compression (as seen in the example above).
- Re-using the RequestCachePolicy (as seen in the example above).
- Setting Expect100Continue to false.
- Setting DefaultConnectionLimit before the ServicePoint is created to a larger number.
- Reusing the HttpWebRequest (does not work as remote host does not support it).
- Increasing the ReceiveBufferSize on the ServicePoint both before and after creation.
- Disabling proxy detection in Internet Explorer's Lan Settings.

My suspicion is not with the remote host as I can quite clearly wrench far more performance out by the methods I explained, but instead that some mechanism is capping the amount amount of data that is allowed to be sent through the HttpWebRequest (maybe something to do with the ServicePoint?). Thanks in advance, and please let me know if there is anything else you need clarifying.

--

Just to expand on the topic, my colleague and I used the same code on a system running Windows Server Standard 2016 64bit and requests using this method run significantly faster and more numerous. This seems to be pointing out that there is likely some sort of software bottleneck imposed proving that there is something going on. The slow operations are observed on Windows 10 Home/Pro 64bit and lower on faster hardware than the server is running on.

Answer (score 0):

**Scaling**

I do not have a better solution for your problem but i think i know why your performance seems to peek or why it is machine dependent.

Usually a program has the best performance when the number of threads or processes matches exactly the number of cores. That is because the system can run them independently and the overhead for scheduling or context switching is minimized.

You arrived at your peek performance at 3 or 4 different tasks. From that i would conclude your machine has 2 or 4 cores. That would exactly match my explanation.

Comment: Only thing is I can run 4 instances of the application each capable of processing 3-4 requests at a time (so up to potentially 16 at once) so I don't think it's core bound, thanks for giving it a shot though :)